# Scanner driver for Epson Eco Tank ET-2710 needed

Tags: scanner, epson

I want to use an Epson ET-2710 all in one printer on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop PC, and am trialling TurboPrint for the printer as I have found nothing else, but am stuck regarding the scanner drivers. 
Found Epson Avaysis but it requires SANE package version 1.0.3 or later to be installed before installing Image Scan! for Linux. Looked at download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html#sec2 instructions for install are there but no drivers as url not found.
dpkg --list returns, sane-utils     1.0.29-0ubuntu5
No progress there!
Can anyone here please help me out by pointing me to an alternative driver that works?
I did find a reference to rpm files but not confident to go down the route of converting files to find they still don't work.
From Download Page for sane-utils_1.0.30-1~experimental2_amd64.deb on AMD64 machines. Does anyone have experience of this? All and any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

[Epson scanner drivers for Linux](https://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php)

You'll find an installation script there after expanding the tar.gz file.
For scanner connection may need to activate wlan connection to wlan router using WPS button of router and activate WPS on printer.

I was able to scan after that using Xsane but only rather poor 75x75 dpi resolution is available.

Comment: "I was able to scan after that using Xsane but only rather poor 75x75 dpi resolution is available." same issue here with latest xane 0.999 and ET 2710, while for printing, the linux drivers from Epson are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

Epson in december 2020 ... so, few days ago, released the latest **Epson Scanner Driver All-in-one package**

after installing the package, mean

- download it (click on the link "Package Download Page")
- extract the folder contained in the archive
- run the contained `./install.sh` script

you'll have the latest EcoTank drivers installed and nevertheless...
you'll be able to run the fantastic `epsonscan2` software